# Executing BPF program within memory management subsystem functions like "__alloc_pages()"

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, ebpf, bpf

I'm new to the world of BPF and kernel programming, and I have a specific requirement. I need to execute a BPF program within memory management subsystem functions, specifically within functions like `__alloc_pages()`. The goal is to apply certain allocation decisions implemented in BPF from userspace.

Since BPF is not directly included in the memory management subsystem, I'm unable to hook a program there. I'm seeking guidance on how to make an arbitrary kernel function execute a BPF program if it's attached from userspace.

Any advice, suggestions, code snippet, or insights on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To be able to do something like this you would need to modify the kernel (and hopefully submit the patch upstream). This use case sounds very much like the TCP tuning or CPU scheduler use cases. It would frankly be to much to make a guide for how to go about exactly your ask here. I would suggest you look at the following resources and patch series to get a feel for how others have approached similar changes in the past:

- https://netdevconf.info/2.2/papers/brakmo-tcpbpf-talk.pdf
- https://lwn.net/Articles/727189/
- https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20221130082313.3241517-1-tj@kernel.org/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/873244/